# create a .php file through the launch of a .bat

Tags: php, batch-file, launch

I need to launch a .bat file that creates a php file, containing this text:

```
<?php
$_mail_mailSpooler = array (
  'classname' => 'mail_mailSpooler',
  'from' => 'test@test.com',
  'array_indirizzi_mail' => 
  array (
    0 =>  ‘lol@hotmail.com’,
  'testo_mail' =>  ‘prova’,
  'filename_html' => NULL,
  'oggetto_mail' => ‘prova’,
  'elenco_allegati' => '',
  'forza_mail_txt' => 0,
  'asl_logger' => '',
  'log_identifier' => NULL,
  'log_in_web' => 0,
  'log_str' => '',
  'nome_file_dump' => '../mailSpooler/mail_incoming/maildda2.php',
);
```

I have tried `echo " (test)" >gnagna.php`

but it doen't work. 
any suggestion please?
thanks

Comment: It's not going work if you're using `‘` and `’` typographic quotes in there.

Answer (score 2):

use type instead of echo - echo's only supposed to give user feedback, file reading and writing is properly done by type. Have a look at http://www.robvanderwoude.com/allhelpw2ksp4_en.php#TYPE for more

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but i'm not already able to launch my php with right code. 
i've tried `type <?php`
`$_mail_mailSpooler = array (`
  `'classname' => 'mail_mailSpooler',`
  `'from' => 'test@test.com',`
  `'array_indirizzi_mail' =>`
 `array (`
   `0 =>  ‘lol@hotmail.com’,`
  `'testo_mail' =>  ‘prova’,`
 `'filename_html' => NULL,`
  `'oggetto_mail' => ‘prova’,`
  `'elenco_allegati' => '',`
  `'forza_mail_txt' => 0,`
 `'asl_logger' => '',`
 `'log_identifier' => NULL,`
 `'log_in_web' => 0,`
  `'log_str' => '',`
  `'nome_file_dump' => '../mailSpooler/mail_incoming/maildda2.php',`
`); C:\>test.php`
but it doesn't work.
moreover your link says that this command displays the content of an existing file and i need to create a new one!